# How to handle subdomains in sitemap index

Tags: sitemap, sitemap.xml

So I have site.com
also there is subdomain.site.com

I've created two separate sitemaps.xml for site.com and subdomain.site.com, let's call them sitemap_main.xml and sitemap_subdomain.xml

Now I need to combine those xml's in single xml file known as "sitemap index"

The question is how to specify the link to subdomain correctly?

Should it be:
site.com/sitemap_main.xml
site.com/sitemap_subdomain.xml

or should it be
site.com/sitemap_main.xml
subdomain.site.com/sitemap_subdomain.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

site.com/sitemap_main.xml
site.com/sitemap_subdomain.xml